# How to pass a data list as an argument in GNU Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, gnu, gnu-assembler

I have 3 different lists in the Data Section of my code. I intend to write a function to find the maximum number of these lists, whichever the user may want to use. How do I correctly pass the address of the required list to the function? And how to I obtain the values from the list using an index? I don't know the proper syntax for indexed addressing on an address I got as an argument. I couldn't find anything helpful on Google.

Here's the code:

### maxfunc.s

```
# NAME:     maxfunc.s
# PURPOSE:  A modular approach of finding the maximum of lists

    .section .data
    # The data section has three lists for testing, change the code
    # highlighted in the text section to change the list passed.
data_1:
    .long 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0
data_2:
    .long 23, 45, 62, 13, 87, 54, 0
data_3:
    .long 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 6, 5, 8, 1, 1, 0

# VARIABLES:
# 1. %edi - Will be our index variable, to access the items
# 2. %ebx - The element we're looking at currently
# 3. %eax - The maximum value we've found so far
# 4. %ecx - To store the address of the list


    .section .text
    # Push the address of the list we want to find the maximum of
    pushl   data_1
    #            ^
    #            +---> Change this to select your list

    call    maximum
    addl    $4, %esp    # Reset the stack

    movl    %eax, %ebx
    movl    $1, %eax
    int     $0x80

    .type   maximum, @function
maximum:
    # Setup
    popl    %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    # The initial setup:
    # Get the address of the list
    # Set the index to 0
    # Get the first item from the list
    # The first item is currently the largest
    movl    $0, %edi
    movl    8(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    (%ecx)(, %edi, 4), %ebx
    movl    %ebx, %eax

max_loop:
    cmpl    $0, %ebx
    je      exit_loop

    incl    %edi
    movl    (%ecx)(, %edi, 4), %ebx

    cmpl    %eax, %ebx
    jle     max_loop

    # %ebx is greater than %eax, therefore, update max
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    jmp     max_loop

exit_loop:
    # Tear down
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

It doesn't compile and shows the following error:

```
maxfunc.s: Assembler messages:
maxfunc.s:47: Error: register value used as expression
maxfunc.s:55: Error: register value used as expression
```

What's the proper way to obtain the address of the data list from the register `%ecx` to use for indexed addressing? Or the parameter?

---

My system is 64 bit, but I'm compiling it as a 32 bit binary (for compliance with [this book](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index addressing mode is like `movq data_set(,%rbx,8), %rax`.

The syntax is like `INSTRUCTION CONST(BASE_ADDR_REG,INDEX_REG,MULTIPLIER`)

You are allowed to omit the base register as I have in my example. The reason I omitted it is because my data address is not changing in my program, so  I use it's immediate value instead.

Where `data_set` is the base address (used as a constant), `%rbx` is the index and `8` is the multiplier...in my case 8 bytes because I am iterating quadword values.

If I was iterating `long` values, like you are, I would use `4` as my multiplier because longs are generally 4 bytes (32 bits) on `x86`.

### Example Max Function

```
.section .data
    data_set: .quad 8, 1, 98, 18, 18, 12, 18, 19, 27, 32, 9, 12, 18, 92, 255, 0

.section .text
.globl _start


# rbx, data index
# rdi, current max
# rax, current data
_start:
    movq $0, %rbx # init index reg
    movq data_set(,%rbx,8), %rax
    movq %rax, %rdi

loop:   
    cmpq $0, %rax # check if end
    je exit
    incq %rbx
    movq data_set(,%rbx,8), %rax
    cmpq %rdi, %rax
    jle loop

    movq %rax, %rdi
    jmp loop

exit:
    movq $60, %rax
    syscall
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to move this to a function that takes `data_set` as an argument. I'm already familiar with the code you posted.

Comment: I tried it... It's not working... Or I don't know the proper way. (See the code and the error)

Comment: try `movl   (%ecx, %edi, 4), %ebx`.

Comment: It compiles but I'm getting a Seg Fault. I'll fix it eventually. Thanks for your help. :-) I'll accept your answer when my code works perfectly.

Comment: `movl    (%ecx, %edi, 4), %ebx` is causing a Seg Fault. :-/ I've verified that `%ecx` storing the correct address, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: `pushl   data_1` pushes the value of the first element in the `data_1` array. Your comment and code are conflicting. You surely intended to push the immediate address value.  Change to `pushl  $data_1`.... now the `popl` can restore the correct value.

Comment: Yes! It works! I didn't know that prefixing is must to obtain its immediate address. Thank you. It works fine now.

Comment: I posted the working code on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156886/finding-the-maximum-of-a-given-list-of-data-in-gnu-assembly-x86-32-bit). Take a look. Add some suggestions if you want.